# How to perform specific tasks for each subclass in the base class constructor

Tags: c++, base-class, pure-virtual

I have a base class. For example:

```cpp
class CData{
public:
    CData(const std::string &_filename)
    {
        m_filename = _filename;
        // LodaData(); // wrong
    }

    virtual void LoadData() = 0;
private:
    std::string m_filename;
};
```

And, a subclass:

```cpp
class COtherData: public CData{
public:
    COtherData(const std::string &_filename): CData(_filename) {}

    virtual void LoadData() {
    // some code to load data
    ...
    }
};
```

I want to know how to perform some tasks in base class for subclasses.

Comment: Why is the `// LodaData(); // wrong` wrong?

Comment: @KamilCuk, because it has no definition in `CData`.

Comment: The problem is that you call virtual function from constructor - you should avoid it. Instead you need to add a function to the base class that will call your virtual functions, which eventually end up with calling overriden function of the child class.

Comment: If `COtherData` wants to load data, let it do it in its own constructor. Why do you think you need force it on `CData`?

Comment: @StoryTeller I have to say that my thoughts are wrong.  >_<. So bad this idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you call virtual function from constructor - you should avoid it. Instead you need to add a function to the base class that will call your virtual functions, which eventually end up with calling overridden function of the child class.
Thus I will change your base class in the following way:

```
class CData
{
public:
    CData(const std::string &_filename)
        : m_filename(_filename)
    {}

    void performTask()
    {
        LoadData();
        // ... do something else
    }

    virtual void LoadData() = 0;
private:
    std::string m_filename;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Create different constructors in the base class, then in the subclass call the appropriate constructor. Or use default arguments that change appropriately.

```
class A  
{  
   A(int a = 0) 
   {
        if(a == 0) // first case
        else // second case
   }

};

class B : public A 
{
    B() : A(0) {} // First case
    --- or --- 
    B() : A(1) {} // Second case
}
```